# Remove multiple elements from deeply nested array with single update query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following type of documents:

```
[
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("5c05984246a0201286d4b57a"),
f: "x",
"_a": [
  {
    "_onlineStore": {}
  },
  {
    "_p": {
      "s": {
        "a": {
          "t": [
            {
              id: 1,
              "dateP": "20200-09-20",
              did: "x",
              dst: "y",
              den: "z"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              "dateP": "20200-09-20"
            }
          ]
        },
        "c": {
          "t": [
            {
              id: 3,
              "dateP": "20300-09-22",
              
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              "dateP": "20300-09-23",
              did: "x",
              dst: "y",
              den: "z"
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              "dateP": "20300-09-23",
              
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
}
]
```

I need to find update query that remove all documents that do not have "did" , "dst" and "den" fields , in the document nested array above this are the sub-objects with id:[2,3,5] , in the real collection I dont know the id's , is there option to remove all at once ?

[My playground attempt , but unsuccessfull](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e1CO6YDH8I7)

The document after the update need to look like:

```
[
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("5c05984246a0201286d4b57a"),
f: "x",
"_a": [
  {
    "_onlineStore": {}
  },
  {
    "_p": {
      "s": {
        "a": {
          "t": [
            {
              id: 1,
              "dateP": "20200-09-20",
              did: "x",
              dst: "y",
              den: "z"
            }
          ]
        },
        "c": {
          "t": [
            {
              id: 4,
              "dateP": "20300-09-23",
              did: "x",
              dst: "y",
              den: "z"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
db.collection.update(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "_a": {
        $map: {
          input: "$_a",
          as: "external",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$$external._p",
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                _p: {
                  s: {
                    a: {
                      t: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$$external._p.s.a.t",
                          as: "item",
                          cond: {
                            $and: [
                              {
                                $gt: [
                                  "$$item.did",
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                $gt: [
                                  "$$item.dst",
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                $gt: [
                                  "$$item.den",
                                  0
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  c: {
                    t: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$external._p.s.c.t",
                        as: "item",
                        cond: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $gt: [
                                "$$item.did",
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $gt: [
                                "$$item.dst",
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $gt: [
                                "$$item.den",
                                0
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "$$external"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
], 
{multi:true})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tlSX2hvfVl8)

Comment: Exactly! Thanks alot @nimrod serok!

Comment: found one issue , not all documents have a.t and a.c , when one of them is missing          "c": {   "t": null   }  appear after update ... :(  , how I can avoid that , I dont want the c.t:null to appear when there is no c in the original document ... I guess this is because of the $filter ?

Comment: I have 2x possible a.t and c.t  , but they are not compulsory in all documents , even there is documents without both  where after the update they will appear as c.t:null  and a.t:null , but this is not expected to happen ...

Comment: added it as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310123/remove-multiple-objects-from-deeply-nested-array